# Issues with json_encode

Tags: javascript, json

i want to retrieve the mail and password and show them as a json format in the `<p>` element. the problem is that when i click on submit, nothing happens.. is that something wrong with my code?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<script>
function myfunction() {
var mail = document.getElementById("mail1").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("password1").value;
        //document.getElementById("ici").innerHTML = mail + " " + pass  ;
        tab['mail'] =  mail;
        tab['password'] =  password;
        var output = json_encode(tab);
        document.getElementById("ici").innerHTML = output;
    }

</script>

Mail: <input type="text"  name="mail" id="mail1">
password: <input type="text"  name="password" id="password1">
<button onclick="myfunction()" > submit</button>

<p>ici: <span id="ici"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: javascript doesn't have json_encode, this is php function

Comment: i mean a tag in the end of the code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you convert something to JSON using `JSON.stringify`, not `json_encode` (which is PHP):

```
var output = JSON.stringify(tab);
```

But your code as quoted will fail because you don't define `tab` anywhere, and you've used `password` rather than `pass` (the name you gave your variable). You may have meant:

```
var mail = document.getElementById("mail1").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("password1").value;
var output = JSON.stringify({
    mail: mail,
    password: pass
});
document.getElementById("ici").innerHTML = output;
```

Or more concisely (but not as easy to debug):

```
document.getElementById("ici").innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
    mail: document.getElementById("mail1").value,
    password: document.getElementById("password1").value
});
```